# what is the difference between localhost:6334 and localhost:{insert username here}?

Tags: html, forms, cgi, webstorm

At least that is what I think is the best way to phrase my question. I am a new programming student and the teacher had this example in his notes that he never was able to get to. What I am doing is making a simple form submission using a cgi script. I am using WebStorm as an IDE and I am running into trouble when I try to submit my form on my webpage. Here are the three files of code that I am using:

html page:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Testing Form submission</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Testing Simple Form</h2>

<form name="test_form" method="post" action="form_submission.sh">
    First Name: <input type="text" name="firstName"/><br/>
    Last Name: <input type="text" name="lastName"/><br/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

cgi script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

source cgi_vars.sh

# register all GET and POST variables
cgi_getvars BOTH ALL

echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo
echo "<html>"
echo "<head>"
echo "<title>Form Submitted</title>"
echo "</head>"
echo "<body>"
echo "<h2>The values you submitted were:</h2>"
echo "First Name: ${firstName}<br/>"
echo "Last Name: ${lastName}<br/>"
echo "</body>"
echo "</html>"
```

and some other file that the script refers to but I don't know exactly what it is for or what it does...:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# (internal) routine to store POST data
function cgi_get_POST_vars()
{
    # check content type
    # FIXME: not sure if we could handle uploads with this..
    [ "${CONTENT_TYPE}" != "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" ] && \
    echo "bash.cgi warning: you should probably use MIME type "\
         "application/x-www-form-urlencoded!" 1>&2
    # save POST variables (only first time this is called)
    [ -z "$QUERY_STRING_POST" \
      -a "$REQUEST_METHOD" = "POST" -a ! -z "$CONTENT_LENGTH" ] && \
        read -n $CONTENT_LENGTH QUERY_STRING_POST
    # prevent shell execution
    local t
    t=${QUERY_STRING_POST//%60//} # %60 = `
    t=${t//\`//}
    t=${t//\$(//}
    t=${t//%24%28//} # %24 = $, %28 = (
    QUERY_STRING_POST=${t}
    return
}

# (internal) routine to decode urlencoded strings
function cgi_decodevar()
{
    [ $# -ne 1 ] && return
    local v t h
    # replace all + with whitespace and append %%
    t="${1//+/ }%%"
    while [ ${#t} -gt 0 -a "${t}" != "%" ]; do
    v="${v}${t%%\%*}" # digest up to the first %
    t="${t#*%}"       # remove digested part
    # decode if there is anything to decode and if not at end of string
    if [ ${#t} -gt 0 -a "${t}" != "%" ]; then
        h=${t:0:2} # save first two chars
        t="${t:2}" # remove these
        v="${v}"`echo -e \\\\x${h}` # convert hex to special char
    fi
    done
    # return decoded string
    echo "${v}"
    return
}

# routine to get variables from http requests
# usage: cgi_getvars method varname1 [.. varnameN]
# method is either GET or POST or BOTH
# the magic varible name ALL gets everything
function cgi_getvars()
{
    [ $# -lt 2 ] && return
    local q p k v s
    # prevent shell execution
    t=${QUERY_STRING//%60//} # %60 = `
    t=${t//\`//}
    t=${t//\$(//}
    t=${t//%24%28//} # %24 = $, %28 = (
    QUERY_STRING=${t}
    # get query
    case $1 in
    GET)
        [ ! -z "${QUERY_STRING}" ] && q="${QUERY_STRING}&"
        ;;
    POST)
        cgi_get_POST_vars
        [ ! -z "${QUERY_STRING_POST}" ] && q="${QUERY_STRING_POST}&"
        ;;
    BOTH)
        [ ! -z "${QUERY_STRING}" ] && q="${QUERY_STRING}&"
        cgi_get_POST_vars
        [ ! -z "${QUERY_STRING_POST}" ] && q="${q}${QUERY_STRING_POST}&"
        ;;
    esac
    shift
    s=" $* "
    # parse the query data
    while [ ! -z "$q" ]; do
    p="${q%%&*}"  # get first part of query string
    k="${p%%=*}"  # get the key (variable name) from it
    v="${p#*=}"   # get the value from it
    q="${q#$p&*}" # strip first part from query string
    # decode and evaluate var if requested
    [ "$1" = "ALL" -o "${s/ $k /}" != "$s" ] && \
        eval "$k=\"`cgi_decodevar \"$v\"`\""
    done
    return
}
```

So when I am in WebStorm and I click on one of the browser options it will pull open the file using localhost:6334/filepath. After doing this when I try to submit the form it starts a download of the cgi script for some reason. However if I navigate to just localhost, I notice that it has all my files ready to go so when I click open the html file from there and submit the form, it works fine with the cgi.

So is there something screwy in my code? Or is there some fundamental difference between the two ways of getting at the html file? Or is there some setting in some server file that I need to change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, WebStorm built-in webserver (that serves files from `localhost:63342/filepath`) is a simple static web server, POST requests like yours are processed using static file handler - i.e the server just returns a content of file available at specified URL - nothing more. You must have a different web server serving files at 'just localhost' that can handle POST requests differently...